# In what exact moment do you change your code version, just after a tag/release or when the tag/release is finished?

Tags: coding-style, version

Let's say you have a bunch of code and let's assume that you have a first working version. This is version 1.0. You go to your git repository and tag the version. Then in that exact moment you have your first tag or release. Then you have in your code version number 1.0 and in your repository tag number 1.0.

My question is, when exactly do you change the version number in the code to version 1.1 (let's assume we don't care about 1.0.1):

A) do you change it right away after the tag 1.0 is done? Therefore all your code from this moment on belongs to version 1.1. This version "ends" when you create a new tag 1.1, which is the stable version 1.1 and change to version 1.2 in the code.

B) do you change it after you have done several code changes and publish your second tag (tag 1.1)? In that case you have a tag version 1.0 of the stable code and you are making improvements in the code. All new changes you do belong to version 1.0. Then when you are finished making changes, you change the code number to 1.1 and the tag number to 1.1

Nerdy question right ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is somewhat subjective but I would strongly suggest A. Branch out at a the time of release and start working in a new branch.

It's because your users are then in sync with where you left off in v1. If you introduce a number of features for the working v1.1 branch and possibly some design changes which kind of strongly branch away from v1, you can always come back to what the users are seeing by updating to the v1 branch.

Branching in this way based on release is useful as "checkpoints" based on what the users actually have, not based on what you intend to deliver. This way when a user reports something, you can easily know which version of the code they're actually using and quickly flick to it.

This also leaves some breathing room to do easy "service patches", like a v1.01. I know you wrote that you don't care about that, but if your users report an issue in v1 that you've already kind of solved in v1.1 or the v1.1 design has changed in a way to make it no longer valid, but you want to sneak some patch in between there, you can update to your v1 branch, make a minor tweak, and release a v1.01 service patch kind of thing. There's a bit more wiggle room there for that kind of thing.

As a hypothetical, imagine a user reports a glitch in v1. You can't reproduce it in your latest development branch. Now does the fact that you can't reproduce it in your current changeset mean it's fixed, or that you simply can't reproduce it? The easiest way to know for sure is to be able to quickly switch and use the same version you released to the user. That's where branching off and kind of freezing the branch at the time of release is useful.

Of course you could do that without branching or tagging at all if you just comment your changesets in a way such that you know which one is which. But then there's little point to tagging/branching in the context of a release. If you do it as an organizational means and a way of isolating changesets to one place, I'd suggest doing it in a way that keeps those branches in sync with what the users actually have.